# Why is CSS from one page being applied to another?

Tags: css, asp.net, webforms

I reorganized some CSS a couple weeks ago, and today realized that I left a style out of a file. Turns out the style, included in a CSS file loaded in another page, is still being applied, so I never realized it was missing.

Here's a snippet of my "first" page (`Default.aspx`):

```
<link href="App_Themes/Placeholder/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="App_Themes/Placeholder/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

where `default.css` has this style (among others that are being "cross-applied?"):

```
.state-icon {
    left: -5px;
}
```

Now, in my "second" page (Approve.aspx), I include these stylesheets:

```
<link href="App_Themes/Placeholder/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="App_Themes/Placeholder/css/approve.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Opening and inspecting Approve.aspx shows me the style is still being found in `default.css`.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjbPJ.png)

[image: the style is still being found in <code>default.css</code>]

These pages don't use a master page. I guess it's not necessarily a "problem" since I'll move the styles anyway, but I'm still curious..

Comment: The style is probably being cached. you need to take this into consideration. I would look into cache-busting asp.net